# I want the image to move along the hypotenuse of its rotating angle but it sometimes goes a different way

Tags: javascript, math

I make my little image to rotate a random angle. And I want it move alone the hypotenuse of this angle.But it will somehow move to a different way.Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>heart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">  
</head>

<body>
    <script>
  // when click, an image pop up
        // use addEventListener to do so 
        let timer=null;
        let imgList=[];
        document.addEventListener("click",function(event){
            let img= document.createElement("img");
            img.style.position="absolute";
            img.style.left=(event.clientX-32)+"px";
            img.style.top=(event.clientY-32)+"px";

            img.src="1.png";

            var de = Math.floor(Math.random()*60-30);
            img.style.transform="rotate(" + de + "deg)";             document.body.appendChild(img);

            setTimeout(draw,1000,de);

            function draw(de){
                 //convert px to intgeter
                 var x=parseInt(img.style.left,10);
                 var y=parseInt(img.style.top,10);
                 var id = setInterval(frame,10);
                 var pos=0;
                 function frame(){
                     if (pos==36){
                         clearInterval(id);
                         img.remove();
                     }
                     else{
                         pos++;
                         img.style.top=(y-pos)+'px';
                         img.style.left=(Math.tan(de)*pos)+x+'px';
                     }
 });
  </script>
</body>
```

Hope someone to help me. Thanks a lot. I’ve think about it for an hour

Comment: `Math.tan` expects the argument being in radians, you're passing degrees. It kinda works, but every time `de % (PI / 2) == 0`, the result changes its sign, which means the direction is changed. You've to convert degrees to radians before passing, `rad = Math.PI / 180 * de`.

Comment: Thanks！It works well for me！